# String problem wheather it is pel or not pel

Tags: visual-c++

String pelindrome or not. There is no syntax error but y it is showing wrong output
Output it is showing:
Noob
Is pel

[image: String pelindrome or not. There is no syntax error but y it is showing wrong output Output it is showing: Noob Is pel]

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char i[]="noop";
  court<<i<<endl;
  (i==strrev(i))?cout<<" pel": cout<<" not pel";
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text in the question, not an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: @RetiredNinja `strcmp` won't help here, as `strrev` reverses in place. The two pointers are always equal, and so of course are the contents they point to.